# Azure Static Web App + Azure Function + PuppeteerSharp gives UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: azure-functions, kudu, puppeteer-sharp, azure-static-web-app

When I deploy my **Azure Static Web App** to Azure with an **Azure Function** which makes use of **PuppeteerSharp**, I see the following error in **Application Insights**:

```
Exception while executing function: ProductsGet Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\3.3.1\32bit\.local-chromium' is denied.
```

If I look locally, there is a 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1' folder with a '.local-chromium' folder within it.

I tried to change the path where the **'.local-chromium'** folder is, with

```
var tempPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "bin/.local-chromium");
var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(new BrowserFetcherOptions
                {
                    Path = tempPath
                });
                await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
                await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(
                    new LaunchOptions
                    {
                        Headless = true,
                        ExecutablePath = browserFetcher.RevisionInfo(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision).ExecutablePath
                    }
                );
```

But that doesn't work. With normal **Azure Functions**, I can have a look with **Kudu** to see the folder structure. Is that also possible with **Azure Static Web Apps**?

Comment: Did you read this post https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-puppeteer-pdf-razor-template/?

Comment: @hardkoded thanks for the link. I haven't read the post. I will give it a try and come back with the result.

Comment: @hardkoded it didn't work.

Althought the azure-pipeline.yml

```trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/angular-app'
      api_location: 'Api'
      output_location: '/dist/angular-app'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)```

tells it to use ubuntu-latest as the vm-image, the Azure Function is deployed on a Windows OS.

I logged `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)`  to ApplicationInsights.

Comment: Hi @AndyMan, did You resolve the problem?